# C Pattern/Idiom for balancing alloc/free

Tags: c, memory-management, allocation, bare-metal

I have a bunch of code that follows a simple pattern:

```
Thing *myThing = newThing(); // allocation happens here
...
thingFuncA(myThing);
... and other computations ...
thingFuncB(myThing);
...
thingFree(myThing);
return result;
```

The application of `thingFuncX()` varies as does the other computations, but the pattern that it is always *free*'ed at the end is always the same.

I need to use raw C here (iow, not C++ with it's fancy scoping allocations), I'm running bare metal on a semi-limited processor.

Is there a way to (ab)use the CPreprocessor to capture this common pattern. I'd like to have an idiom I use so I can have confidence that a free won't be forgotten. I think I could maybe do something with a macro and a `while { } do ()` (an answer that was an example would help in that case). Or maybe there's some other clever C trick I'm overlooking?

Comment: So what you're looking for is essentially a destructor in C. ;)

Comment: Ideally you would like to do such allocations on the stack, and avoid all the problems related to memory management, but if the API only exposes `newThing()`, then it's really not an option....

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Thing in this case is a `Dictionary` like entity. So the intermediate APIs can change it's memory footprint. I'm not sure how you'd keep that on the stack, given it's dynamic nature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC provides the `cleanup` attribute which essentially allows you to have scope-based destructors in C:

```
void function(void) {
    Thing *myThing __attribute__((cleanup(callback))) = newThing();
    ...
    thingFuncA(myThing);
    thingFuncB(myThing);
}

void callback(Thing **thing) {
    thingFree(*thing);
}
```

Comment: There's a blog on the topic: [C smart pointers](http://snaipe.me/c/c-smart-pointers/)

Comment: Wow. I really need to learn more of the \_\_attribute__ stuff that GCC provides. That's twice now it's come to my rescue. Your solution was exactly what I needed. I learned that these cannot be attached to the type via `typedef` but must be attached to the variabl itself.